# Assigning values to non existing keys/indices in python dictionaries/lists

Tags: python

Why is it that we can add new elements to a dictionary by directly assigning a key-value pair but not do the same lists:-

For example:

```
dictl = {}
dictl['new_key'] = value
print dictl  # prints {'new_key: value}
```

But,

```
listl = []
listl[0] = value   # IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. They have different internal representations and use cases.
2. Extending a list is not a trivial operation and thus should not be
   done trivially, implicitly.
3. What will you put to unused indices in an extended list?
4. Dictionary does not suffer from this since adding a new key/value
   pair has no other side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve my aim of updating nonexistent indexes using list.inssert(index, item).
However, note that if the index to insert at is greater than **len(list) - 1** , the item will be appended to the list. For e.g

```
 list = []
 list[0] = 5 #indexError, but
 list.insert(0, 5) # works => list = [5]
```

indexes > len(list) - 1

```
 list = [1, 3]
 list.insert(4, 8) # => [1, 3,
```